# Custom ir.actions.server

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to make a custom `ir.actions.server` for a model like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
<data>

<record model="ir.actions.server" id="action_recruitment_request_filter">
    <field name="name">Filter</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="fhid_recruitment.model_recruitment_request"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = model.my_action()</field>
</record>
```

And in the model like this

```
class RecruitmentRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'recruitment.request'

    @api.multi
    def my_action(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'recruitment.request',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'target': 'current',
            'context': {
                'search_default_my_requests': 1
            }
        }
```

But I cannot see this function taking effect to the view. Even if I uncomment the `set_trace()` I don't see it enter the method. What am I missing here?

Here is the menu with the action

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_hr_recruitment_request">
    <field name="name">Requests</field>
    <field name="res_model">recruitment.request</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="form_view_id" ref="recruitment_request_form_view" />
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="hr_recruitment_request_view_search" />
    <field name="view_id" ref="hr_recruitment_request_tree" />
    <field name="context"></field>
    <!-- <field name="context" eval="{'search_default_by_responsible': 1}" /> -->
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create the first recruitment request
        </p><p>

        </p>
    </field>
</record>

<menuitem parent="hr_recruitment.menu_hr_recruitment_root" id="menu_hr_recruitment_request" 
    action="action_hr_recruitment_request" name="Requests" sequence="-1" />
```

Comment: The code inside the action should be `action = model.my_action()`. Beside that i don't see any suspicious things...

Comment: OK I have changed it to `action = model.my_action()` . Still no effect to it. I have even created a new database and install my addons again.

Comment: and you call that action by a button?

Comment: sorry, menu item, i've already forgotten :D

Comment: tested it on a [12.0 runbot](http://624126-12-0-dd3e9a.runbot20.odoo.com/) and it's working as intended.

Comment: Can you share your `menuitem`? The screenshot is not helping very much, you can delete it. ;-)

Comment: uhm, you should set the server action as action of your menu item.

Comment: menu item is using `ir.actions.act_window` and it is not `ir.actions.server` I thought they were different?

Comment: Try to create one in the client by yourself and you will see, you can use any type of `ir.actions` in menu items. Maybe you have to use `<record>` instead of `<menuitem>` which is a shortcut and IMO a bad shortcut for XML files...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I would never know we can use any type of `ir.actions`

Comment: I recommend to every Odoo developer to look into Settings/technical. There is a lot of nice stuff. When having an overview of that stuff a look into the code behind it is the next thing to do ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server action has to be used in the `<menuitem>` as action.

Comment: Sorry another noob question, the menuitem now works. But the title on top of the tree is "Unnamed". I have tried using `'name' : 'Requests'` in the returned `act_windows` but still "Unnamed"

Comment: LOL sorry I forgot to restart odoo service.

Comment: the classic ;-)